# Working with other date_format with laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4, php-carbon

I'm trying to get other dateformat to work in laravel 4. I want that the user can input something like "31.12.2013" (Format: d.m.Y).

Therefore i'm using this rules in the model

```
public static $rules = array(       
        'birthDate' => 'sometimes|date|date_format:d.m.Y' 
    );
```

Now the user can enter the date in the wished format and the validator accepts the format. The Problem i have is, that the update statement is executed like this.

```
array(3) {
  ["query"]=>
  string(68) "update `people` set `birthDate` = ?, `updated_at` = ? where `id` = ?"
  ["bindings"]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(10) "30.11.2014"
    [1]=>
    string(19) "2014-06-19 19:39:57"
    [2]=>
    string(2) "22"
  }
  ["time"]=>
  float(0,67)
}
```

The birthDate-field has the type date and therefore needs a other format (like the "updated_at" field).

Do i have to work with my own setBirthDateAttribute($value) method? or id there a neater possibility to fix this?

Comment: Yes you may use a mutator method to set the date.

Comment: hmm, this seems to be a little bit confusing to me. if i set the type to date in the rules, laravel should already know that the given value should be converted to date. Therefore i think that laravel should do this by them self, what do you think about?

Comment: No, because date representations aren't standardized. You might well want to store it as a string, or you might be using a database engine with a different standard format.

Comment: ok, you're right, then a own setAttribute method is the solution to use :) thanks